# How to send response to client after for loop completed in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, for-loop, response

I know this question is duplicate, but I have searched over the internet but I haven't get solution.

I have an array of id, on every id I make some calculation. For calculation I have get data from two tables. After calculation for all ids I want to send data to client site.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
let selLicSql =
  "SELECT LD.e_lic_id AS lic_id,LD.license_number AS UPIN ,U.company_name AS agency_name, z.zone_name AS zone FROM license_details AS LD INNER JOIN users AS U ON LD.user_id = U.user_id LEFT JOIN mst_zone AS Z ON LD.zone_id = Z.zone_id WHERE `is_lic_fee_paid` = 1 ORDER BY LD.e_lic_id ASC";
var sel_date_time_stamp = new Date(sel_Date).getTime();
var query = db.query(selLicSql, (err, lic_id_res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("err in sel lic id", err);
  } else {
    if (lic_id_res != "") {
      var data = [];
      var arrLen = lic_id_res.length;
      console.log("arrLen", arrLen);
      for (let i = 0, n = lic_id_res.length; i < n; i++) {
        let sqlSel14115Demand =
          "SELECT * FROM demand_details_14_15 WHERE lic_fee_due_date <= ? AND lic_id = ? ORDER BY demand_details_14_15_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        let sql1415Demand = db.query(
          sqlSel14115Demand,
          [sel_Date, lic_id_res[i]["lic_id"]],
          (err, bal1415Result) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("err in sel demand 14 15", err);
              throw err;
            } else {
              /**code to calculate 14-15 OS */
              var old_lic_fee = 0;
              var old_till_date_lpc = 0;
              var old_online_lpc = 0;
              var old_total_amount = 0;
              var old_payable_lic_fee = 0;
              var old_payable_lpc = 0;
              var old_total_payable_amt = 0;
              if (bal1415Result != "") {
                var old_bal_row = bal1415Result[0];
                var old_lic_fee_due_Date = old_bal_row.lic_fee_due_date;
                var old_lic_fee_due_Date_TimeStamp = new Date(
                  old_lic_fee_due_Date
                ).getTime();
                old_lic_fee = old_bal_row.lic_fee;
                var old_lpc = old_bal_row.lpc;
                var old_diff =
                  sel_date_time_stamp - old_lic_fee_due_Date_TimeStamp;
                var old_days_diff = Math.round(old_diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
                if (old_lic_fee > 0) {
                  old_online_lpc = Math.round(
                    (old_lic_fee * 0.18 * old_days_diff) / 365
                  );
                  old_till_date_lpc = old_online_lpc + old_lpc;
                  old_total_amount = Math.round(
                    old_lic_fee + old_till_date_lpc
                  );
                } else {
                  old_online_lpc = 0;
                  old_till_date_lpc = old_online_lpc + old_lpc;
                  old_total_amount = Math.round(
                    old_lic_fee + old_till_date_lpc
                  );
                }
              } else {
                old_lic_fee = 0;
                old_till_date_lpc = 0;
                old_total_amount = old_lic_fee + old_till_date_lpc;
              }
              if (old_lic_fee > 0) {
                old_payable_lic_fee = old_lic_fee;
              } else {
                old_payable_lic_fee = 0;
              }
              if (old_till_date_lpc > 0) {
                old_payable_lpc = old_till_date_lpc;
              } else {
                old_payable_lpc = 0;
              }
              old_total_payable_amt = Math.round(
                old_payable_lic_fee + old_payable_lpc
              );
              /**END Code to calculate 14-15 OS */
              /**code to calucalte reqgular OS */
              let sqlSel =
                "SELECT * FROM demand_details WHERE lic_fee_due_date <= ? AND lic_id = ? ORDER  BY demand_id DESC LIMIT 1";
              let sqlQuery = db.query(
                sqlSel,
                [sel_Date, lic_id_res[i]["lic_id"]],
                (err, balResult) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("regular bal sel err", err);
                  } else {
                    if (balResult != "") {
                      var balance_row_data = balResult[0];
                      let lic_fee_due_Date = balance_row_data.lic_fee_due_date;
                      let lic_fee_due_Date_TimeStamp = new Date(
                        lic_fee_due_Date
                      ).getTime();
                      var lic_fee = balance_row_data.lic_fee;
                      var old_lpc = balance_row_data.lpc;
                      var difference =
                        sel_date_time_stamp - lic_fee_due_Date_TimeStamp;
                      let dayDiff = Math.round(
                        difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
                      );
                      let online_lpc = 0;
                      let lpc_Till_date = 0;
                      var new_total_balance = 0;
                      let payable_amount = 0;
                      let payable_lic_fee = 0;
                      let payable_lpc = 0;
                      if (lic_fee > 0) {
                        online_lpc = Math.round(
                          (lic_fee * 0.18 * dayDiff) / 365
                        );
                        lpc_Till_date = online_lpc + old_lpc;
                        new_total_balance = Math.round(lic_fee + lpc_Till_date);
                      } else {
                        online_lpc = 0;
                        lpc_Till_date = online_lpc + old_lpc;
                        new_total_balance = Math.round(lic_fee + lpc_Till_date);
                      }
                      var grand_total_bal =
                        new_total_balance + old_total_amount;
                      if (lic_fee > 0) {
                        payable_lic_fee = lic_fee;
                      } else {
                        payable_lic_fee = 0;
                      }
                      if (lpc_Till_date > 0) {
                        payable_lpc = lpc_Till_date;
                      } else {
                        payable_lpc = 0;
                      }
                      payable_amount = Math.round(
                        payable_lpc + payable_lic_fee
                      );
                      var grand_payable_bal =
                        payable_amount + old_total_payable_amt;
                      data.push({
                        upin: lic_id_res[i]["UPIN"],
                        agency: lic_id_res[i]["agency_name"],
                        zone: lic_id_res[i]["zone"],
                        old_lic_fee: old_lic_fee,
                        old_lpc: old_till_date_lpc,
                        old_total_bal: old_total_amount,
                        old_payable_os: old_total_payable_amt,
                        lic_fee: lic_fee,
                        current_lpc: lpc_Till_date,
                        new_total_amount: new_total_balance,
                        payable_amount: payable_amount,
                        grand_total_bal: grand_total_bal,
                        grand_payable_bal: grand_payable_bal,
                      });
                      //console.log('data in loop',data);
                      if (arrLen == i - 1) {
                        console.log("in if");
                        var resTosend = {
                          status: "success",
                          data: data,
                          error_type: "",
                        };
                        return res.send(JSON.stringify(resTosend));
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        );
      }
      //console.log('data',data);
    }
  }
});
```

How can I send data after for loop is completed?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you facing an issue due to async nature of the Node JS? You want to make it sync right?

Comment: @DhruvRajkotia yes i am facing issue due to async. i want to make it sync. i have read about promise but i don't know how to use it as i am new in node js. can u please help me.